# Как вывести строку, если значение переменной не равно 0

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно вывести строку, если `$tablerows[18]` не равно `0`. Как это сделать?

```php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "pass");
mysql_select_db("namedb", $db);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gb_users", $db);
echo("<table border ='2'>");
echo("<tr><td>Значение</td><td>Значение 2</td><td>Значение 3</td><td>Значение 4</td></tr>");
while ($tablerows = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
  echo("<tr></tr><tr><td>$tablerows[1]</td><td>$tablerows[3]</td><td>$tablerows[8]</td><td>$tablerows[18]</td></tr> <tr></tr> ");
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($db);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как это будет выглядеть. Проверял работает     ﻿

```
<?php
      $db = mysql_connect("localhost","login","pass");
      mysql_select_db("namedb" ,$db);
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gb_users" ,$db);
      echo ("<table border ='2'>");
      echo ("<tr><td>Значение 1</td><td>Значение 2</td><td>Значение 3</td><td>Значение 4</td></tr>");
      while ($tablerows = mysql_fetch_row($sql))
      {
    if ($tablerows[18] != 0){
      echo("<tr></tr><tr><td>$tablerows[1]</td><td>$tablerows[3]</td><td>$tablerows[8]</td><td>$tablerows[18]</td></tr> <tr></tr> "); 
      }
      }
      echo "</table>";
      mysql_close($db);
      ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле *PHP* тут не причем и не нужен. Не смотря на то, что можно поставить условие `if ($tablerows[18] !== 0)`, проще сделать правильную выборку из самой БД.

То есть выборка будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
SELECT *
FROM gb_users
WHERE TRIM(myCol) <> '' /* WHERE `myCol` IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(myCol) <> '' */
```

где `myCol` - имя той колонки, которая проверяется на пустоту.

Тогда в цикле никакие условия не нужны. Ибо в финальной выборке уже не будет тех ненужных строк с данными.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "pass");
mysql_select_db("namedb", $db);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gb_users", $db);
echo("<table border ='2'>");
echo("<tr><td>Значение</td></tr>");
$tablerows = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
if (isset($tablerows[18]) && $tablerows[18] !== 0) {
  echo('<tr><td>' . $tablerows[18] . '</td></tr>');
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($db);
```